# Disable editing in other rows for ng-grid while one row is in edit mode

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

**functionality**

I have a ng-grid. One column has an "edit" button. Once you click on edit button the "edit" button gets disabled and "cancel" and "remove" gets enabled and all the columns of the row becomes editable.

**Issue**

I am able to edit multiple rows at a time. This is not expected behavior.

**Expected behavior**

When one row is already in edit mode. And I click on the edit button in some other row, then the previous editable row should become un-editable.
-->Edited value in previous row should be reverted.
--> Only one row at a give point can be editable.

Here is the link of what I have tried.
[Plnkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/RCMO7R?p=preview)

**html code**

```
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="ng-grid@*" data-semver="2.0.14" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/v2.0.14/ng-grid.css" />
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-grid/2.0.11/ng-grid.debug.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>

    </div>
    <button ng-show="row.entity.edit" id="cancelBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="cancel(row)" >Cancel</button>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
var m = angular.module("myApp", ["ngGrid"]);
m.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

  //console.log("Here I need to know which button was selected " + row.entity.name)
  var removeTemplate = '<input type="button" value="remove" ng-click="removeRow(row)" />';
  var ageTextBoxTemplate = '<div class="ngCellText"><div ng-show="!row.entity.edit[{{row.rowIndex}}]">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</div>' +
    '<div ng-show="row.entity.edit[{{row.rowIndex}}]" class="ngCellText"><input type="text" ng-model="row.entity.age"/></div></div>';
  var nameTextBoxTemplate = '<div class="ngCellText"><div ng-show="!row.entity.edit">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</div>' +
    '<div ng-show="row.entity.edit" class="ngCellText"><input type="text" ng-model="row.entity.name"/></div></div>';
  var editButtonTemplate = '<button ng-show="!row.entity.edit" id="editBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="edit(row)" >Edit</button>' +
    '<button ng-show="row.entity.edit" id="cancelBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="cancel(row)" >Cancel</button> ' +
    '<button ng-show="row.entity.edit" id="saveBtn{{row.rowindex}}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="save(row)" >Save</button> ';
  //var checkboxTemplate='<input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.entity.object.dude" ng-click="toggle(row)">';
  var checkboxTemplate = '<input ng-show="!row.entity.edit" type="checkbox" ng-model="row.entity.object.edit" disabled=true>' +
    '<input ng-show="row.entity.edit" type="checkbox" ng-model="row.entity.object.edit">';

  $scope.tempdata = {
    name: "",
    age: "",
    flag: false
  }

  $scope.edit = function(row) {
    row.entity.edit[row.rowIndex] = !  row.entity.edit[row.rowIndex];

    $scope.tempdata.name = row.entity.name;
    $scope.tempdata.age = row.entity.age;
    $scope.tempdata.flag = row.entity.object.edit;
  };

  $scope.cancel = function(row) {
    row.entity.edit = !row.entity.edit;

    row.entity.name = $scope.tempdata.name;
    row.entity.age = $scope.tempdata.age;
    row.entity.object.edit = $scope.tempdata.flag;
  };

  $scope.save = function(row) {
    row.entity.edit = !row.entity.edit;
    if($scope.tempdata.flag === row.entity.object.edit){
      alert("value not changed");
    }
    console.log(row.entity);

  };

  $scope.removeRow = function(row) {
    var index = row.rowIndex;
    $scope.gridOptions.selectItem(index, false);
    $scope.myData.splice(index, 1);
  };

  $scope.myData = [{
      name: "Rajesh",
      age: 27,
      edit: false,
      object: {
        edit: true
      }

    },

    {
      name: "Saurav",
      age: 31,
      object: {
        edit: true
      }
    },

    {
      name: "Rajubabu",
      age: 32,
      object: {
        edit: false
      }
    }, {
      name: "Joby",
      age: 37,
      object: {
        edit: true
      }
    }, {
      name: "Manish",
      age: 41,
      object: {
        edit: false
      }
    }, {
      name: "Sidhansu",
      age: 31,
      object: {
        edit: true
      }
    }
  ];

$scope.gridOptions = {
  data: 'myData',
  enableRowSelection: true,
  //showSelectionCheckbox: true,
  enablePaging: true,
  enableColumnResize: true,
  columnDefs: [{
      field: 'name',
      displayName: 'Name',
      cellTemplate: nameTextBoxTemplate
    }, {
      field: 'age',
      displayName: 'Age',
      cellTemplate: ageTextBoxTemplate
    }, {
      displayName: 'Edit/Cancel/Save',
      cellTemplate: editButtonTemplate
    }, {
      displayName: 'Delete',
      cellTemplate: removeTemplate
    }, {
      field: 'edit',
      displayName: 'edit',
      cellTemplate: checkboxTemplate
    }

  ]
};
});
```

A plnkr of solution would be highly appreciated.

Comment: maintain the table mode. so if someone clicks on edit button set mode to edit. now add ng-disable on your edit button template which return true if mode=edit.. when someone clicks on save/cancel reset the mode to view...

Comment: I am not using a table here .

Comment: i mean to say create a varible on $scope. lets say $scope.tableMode, where you should maintain the mode of the table